# My Camera view and renders blank

Tags: rendering, camera

After modifying an object I deleted the camera, and after that I add a new camera to the scene but in the end I couldn't see anything with my new camera view with <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> and rendering, it just shows blank.

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

[Blender File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s4q1kz7d7dtp88j/nocameraview.blend?dl=0)

Comment: That file is corrupted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the scene camera was set to the mesh itself, instead of the Camera:

[image]

Just imagine: Can you see your own face without a mirror in real world? :P

Solution is simple: Go to **Scene** tab (located in *Property Editor*), use the actual camera object instead of the default one. Or select the camera object then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to set it as the active Camera to the scene.

Another issue in this case is that the *Aperture* type of the camera was set to **Radius**, which makes everything blurry with current parameters. Or you can simply switch to **F-Stop** to solve the blank render issue:

[image]

Comment: HEii.. it WORKS ... thankyou LEon cheung for the help, And the next problem is .. my rendered still black, LOL can you help me ?

Comment: OK, I think I found another why. See updated answer. :)

Comment: Wowww .. amazing, thank you Leon, It works :)

Comment: Vote? for sure.. how to vote?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is wrong exactly with your file, some sort of glitch.

I created a new camera object, switched to it as active camera with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>, then switched back to your originally created camera and it started displaying correctly again.

Make sure you clear your camera objects scale with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and make sure you adjuts the clipping limits so your objects are within the visible area.

Comment: Thankyou for Helping me ... Now I can see through my camera but my render still blank ..

Answer (score 0):

## Focus Distance must not equal 0

In my case, the problem was that "Distance" was set to 0. Perhaps the object it was supposed to focus on was deleted at some point without me noticing.

Set a Focus object or set a manual value greater than 0.

[image: Camera settings]