# Blender won't render... All White

Tags: rendering

I have no bloody idea what setting I changed or what but the file used to render fine and now when I press F12, it instantly spits out a "finished render" of pure white. I've worked so hard on this animation. I can't redo it all in another file.

Oh and other files render fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps similar to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200902/blender-render-output-is-completely-white)

Comment: or take a look at the Outliner to check if something is hidden in viewport but visible in render

Comment: Neither of those, unfortunately. I think I've tried everything I could find.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the file so I can take a closer look? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Read through the many different options on these links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56020/my-camera-view-and-renders-blank and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up